# Не удалось найти хранимую процедуру

Tags: mysql, sql-server

У меня возникла проблема, я создал базу, а работать с ней не могу. Какую-бы я команду не вызывал у меня ошибка

> "Не удалось найти хранимую процедуру <команда>".

Гугл облазил, ничего толкового не нашел.
Работаю на win 10, через Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/DB/themes.txt'
INTO TABLE themes
CHARACTER SET cp1251;
```

> Не удалось найти хранимую процедуру "LOAD".  Неправильный синтаксис
>   около конструкции "LOCAL".  Неверный синтаксис около "INFILE".
>   Неверный синтаксис около ";".

Comment: Я работаю с SQL-sever-ом, вызываю я команду, зарезервированные слова которые выделяются синим цветом в среде,а конкретно сейчас LOAD когда я пытаюсь загрузить данные с файла , и ещё одна проблема:"Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "AFTER"." в запросе:
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column1_name VARCHAR(100) AFTER column2_name;
Но в нём написано всё правильно.

Comment: `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/DB/themes.txt'
INTO TABLE themes
CHARACTER SET cp1251;`
Не удалось найти хранимую процедуру "LOAD".
Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "LOCAL".
Неверный синтаксис около "INFILE".
Неверный синтаксис около ";".

Comment: О каком меню идёт речь?

Comment: Писать NULL пробовал.

Answer (score 5):

В **SQL Server** не определено таких операторов/ключевых слов, как `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. Это будет работать для **MySQL**. Ваш вопрос недостаточно описывает ситуацию, чтобы понять, что же Вы хотите сделать и что Вы имеете. Поэтому следует дополнить свой вопрос деталями. Сейчас можно понять, что Вы пытаетесь заполнить таблицу из файла. **SQL Server** позволяет делать это так:

```
BULK
INSERT themes
FROM 'C:/DB/themes.txt'
WITH
   (
      FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
   )
GO
```

Аналогично и относительно этого:

> Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "AFTER"." в запросе: ALTER
>   TABLE table_name ADD column1_name VARCHAR(100) AFTER column2_name;
>
> Но в нём написано всё правильно

**SQL Server** не поддерживает такую конструкцию и добавлять колонки с определённым порядком следования нельзя, это синтаксис для **MySQL**.